# JsonSchema number validation with multiple ranges

Tags: jsonschema

Is there a supported way (without using the `anyOf` keyword) to specify multiple ranges for a number in JsonSchema?

E.g., a value can either be in the range of 0-10 or 50-100 (the range of 10 < x < 50 is considered invalid).

The `anyOf` keyword can be used as follows:

```json
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 10
    },
    {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 5,
      "maximum": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

Additionally, if the only allowed values were whole integers, I could use an `enum` and actually hand-specify each allowed number, but obviously that's less ideal than specifying ranges.

So, just wondering if there is a way to accomplish this with something like a "restrictions" keyword:

```json
//NOTE: the below is not actually supported (I don't think), just using it as an example of what I'm interested in
{
  "type": "number",
  "restrictions": [
    {
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 10
    },
    {
      "minimum": 50,
      "maximum": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, for those wondering *why* if `anyOf` is available, it's that I have some custom tooling to maintain and supporting `anyOf` would be more of a lift than something that is specific to numeric validation.

Comment: If you have custom tooling and you want to add keywords to do your own special things, assuming you don't care about interoperability or reuse in other locations, you might as well not use JSON Schema and in stead use a language specific validation tool.

Comment: > you might as well not use JSON Schema. Seems a bit shortsighted. JSONSchema is wonderful and provides a lot of value, adding support for custom keywords doesn't need to mean that we should throw the whole thing out. OpenAPI used (and still uses) a slightly-varied version of JSONSchema to support defining schemas, so there's a pretty high-profile example where it makes a lot of sense to go this way.

Comment: > JSONSchema is wonderful and provides a lot of value - Oh, I'd very much agree. I'm actually the only full time person working on JSON Schema, and lead the org itself right now  - What I was saying was, if you might need to do things which JSON Schema doesen't allow, you might find it easier in the long run to use a tool which allows you to easily create and manage business logic. - I'm very well informed when it comes to what things use JSON Schema! =D - OpenAPI 3.1 supports full JSON Schema by the way.

Comment: Well, pleased to meet your e-acquaintance, and thanks for all the great work! Your language, specifically "you might as well not use JSON Schema" seemed a bit like a suggestion to toss the baby out with the bathwater. But, I think I understand a bit better now. JSONSchema, in this case, actually does do what I want it to do, I just was crossing my fingers that it maybe did it in a slightly different way (that different way would just make life a little easier for maintaining my custom JSON Schema validator).

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe is exactly why `anyOf` exists. So no, if you want to express a logical OR, you need to implement the keyword that implements that. I don't see why adding a new custom keyword would make things any easier.

Comment: I would actually argue adding a new keyword would make things harder, reducing the interoperability.

Comment: > I don't see why adding a new custom keyword would make things any easier.

Tried to address this in the question itself.

Also, for those wondering why if anyOf is available, it's that I have some custom tooling to maintain and supporting anyOf would be more of a lift than something that is specific to numeric validation.

Comment: Feel free to add any new new keywords you like, but only your tool will support it. Which reduces interoperability, as stated earlier.